# Liferay 7: While deploying a service using service builder i am getting a bundle exception

Tags: java, liferay, osgi-bundle, liferay-service-builder, liferay-dxp

I am new to liferay 7 and while going through its tutorials, when i tried to build a new service using service builder during its deployment i am getting this bundle exception,

```
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.model; version="[1.0.0,1.1.0)"
```

In gogo shell my services are showing as installed but when i try to start them then it throws above error.

I have tried googling it but could not found its solution. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

**Service-api build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bndlib", version: "3.1.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.osgi.util", version: "3.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.core", version: "6.0.0"
}
```

**Service-servce build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bndlib", version: "3.1.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.osgi.util", version: "3.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.spring.extender", version: "2.0.0"
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.6.0"
    compileOnly project(":modules:SampleService:SampleService-api")
}

buildService {
    apiDir = "../SampleService-api/src/main/java"
}
```

group = "com.demo"

Comment: have you add your package in the export package in bnd.bnd file ?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the tutorials were made for an earlier version of the portal. Your module was installed but it cannot transition to active due to its missing dependency. 
You will want to go through the dependencies you declared and update their version numbers.